# Python Pyspark: reduceByKey summation error

Tags: python, pyspark

I created a list of tuples in my data that look something like this:

```py
rdd.take(10)
[(u'AK', 224), (u'AK', 696), (u'AK', 278), (u'AK', 187), (u'AK', 842), (u'AK', 589), (u'AK', 253), (u'AK', 974), (u'AK', 37), (u'AK', 132)]
```

With this data, I want to use a `mapValues` and `reduceByKey` function to essentially add all my data for AK together. I understand that this is all in in unicode so I can convert my data by doing something like this:

```
states = rdd.mapValues(lambda x: int(x))
states.take(10)
[(u'AK', 224), (u'AK', 696), (u'AK', 278), (u'AK', 187), (u'AK', 842), (u'AK', 589), (u'AK', 253), (u'AK', 974), (u'AK', 37), (u'AK', 132)]
```

However, I keep getting an error when I try to implement my `reducebyKey` function. Which is:

```
states = states.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: (x+y)).collect()
```

I keep getting an error:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,643'
```

Can someone please tell me what is going on and lend some help please? :(

UPDATE:

So I figured out that some of the key values in my list of tuples will come out as "1,529" for instance. I need to remove the comma in order to convert this to int. I am now just struggling to find a good method to go about this. Is there a way I can use .replace(",", "") in a mapping function to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to add it to the mapvalues function: `lambda x: int(x.replace(…))`.

Hope this helps.